# Outlook runtime error '-2147417851 (80010105)'

Tags: vba, outlook

I have an Outlook function that, as of Friday the 3rd May 2019 has started throwing the following error:

```
Run-time error '-2147417851 (80010105)':  
Method 'Open' of object "Workbooks' failed
```

This is the code up to the error point:

```
Sub CreateDictionary()
Dim start
Dim finish

start = Timer
Dim path As String

'***---Declarations---***
Dim MyEmail As Object
Dim xl As New Excel.Application
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim Sheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim ExcelFileName As String
Dim j As Integer
Dim jMax As Variant
Dim entry As String

'***---Set Required Variables---***
ExcelFileName = "\\HYPER\CURRENT JOBS\USEFUL STUFF\Active Jobs DB.xlsm"
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFileName, 0, True)
```

I have checked the filename and it is fine. I have double checked my entries in the `xl.Workbooks.Open` command and nothing changes. I have read elsewhere that this is a Windows 10 issue, though I could not find any guidance to fixing the issue.

Has anyone here had a similar problem?

EDIT:
I have created a temporary workaround by opening the required workbook and using the following code:

```
On Error Resume Next
Set wb = GetObject("\\HYPER\CURRENT JOBS\USEFUL STUFF\Active Jobs DB.xlsm")

If Err <> 0 Then
    MsgBox ("Please open Active Jobs Database and try again")
    Exit Sub
End If

On Error GoTo 0
```

It is currently working but it is obviously not as streamlined as my previous code. If anyone can find out why this is happening, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: If you cut/paste the file name, go to Excel, Use File->Open->Browse and Paste the file name to the File name-box: Can you open the file?

Comment: Does it work if you change the ExcelFileName variable  to point to a local file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41801050

Comment: @FunThomas Yes that still works.

Comment: @dmitry Streblechenko no that doesn't work.

Comment: @0m3r I tried the options in that but it still gives the same error.

Comment: Which office are you on? 64 or 32 version - 2016.....

Comment: @0m3r Office 2010 32bit (Version 14.0.7232.5000)

Comment: Try one more thing , rename the file with out spaces- use one word name

Comment: @0m3r I tried that when I tested if a local file works - filename was "Book1.xlsx". I have been looking at it a bit more today, and it appears to open an instance of Excel, but then throws an error before it opens properly. When I close the instances of excel in task manager, then open excel I get the "Recovered Documents" pane on the right full of instances of the document that never opened properly. I use this code everyday so its super frustrating!

Comment: I just edited the original post with a temporary workaround