Cannot get Outlook from Excel on a Windows 11 computer
I have a macro that can send emails through Outlook from inside Excel 365
The macro works on computers running in Windows 10
But the same macro installed on a computer running Windows 11 returns the error:
Run-time error '429':
ActiveX component cannot run object
The problem is GetObject as in this code
Function Test()
Dim MyOLApp As Outlook.Application
Set MyOLApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
End Function

Outlook is running
The reference to Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library is ticked.
The code is compiled
MyOLApp seems to has all the methods and procedures available (by adding a dot: eg MyOLApp.ActiveExplorer)
The same problem happen in Access
GetObject works with Word, but not Excel or Outlook
CreateObject does create a new instance of Outlook, but not linked to the Outlook already running
I can create a new email, but the computer cannot send it because there is no account.
On a Windows 10 computer the code gets a reference to Outlook and then creates an email
On a windows 11 computer it fails
Everything else looks the same
(but presumably something is not)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67738251/createobjectoutlook-application-not-working-on-some-computers-with-office-36 - did you see this answer?

Did you try with just Dim MyOLApp?

I have discovered the problem
We were using Outlook New, instead of Outlook classic
This came to light when I tried to attach a macro to the quick access toolbar, which does not exist in Outlook new.
Alastair
